# How to get facebook token code via curl?

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I tried use easy curl to get facebook `code` and `access_token` via curl. So that I can post message to my wall. I know `sdk`, but if I only use easy `curl` way?

some fault return:

`Method Not Implemented`

`Invalid method in request`

Here is my code. BY THE WAY: How to remember a `access_token` if it is still valid in 1 hour period time? Thanks.

```
$code_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($canvas_page_url)."&type=client_cred&display=page&scope=user_photos,publish_stream,read_stream,user_likes";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$code_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
$fb_code = curl_exec($ch); // get code
curl_close($ch);

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($canvas_page_url)."&code=".$fb_code."";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$token_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
echo $result; //get token for post to wall
```

EDIT:

```
   $app_id = "14XXXXXXXX";
   $app_secret = "77XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
   function get_app_access_token($app_id, $secret) {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
    $token_params = array(
        "type" => "client_cred",
        "client_id" => $app_id,
        "client_secret" => $app_secret
        );
    return str_replace('access_token=', '', post_url($url, $token_params));
  }
  $token = get_app_access_token($app_id,$app_secret);
  echo $token;
```

Comment: In your edit you don't show the post_url method - did you also copy/paste this into your sample?

Comment: @DSchultz, yes, I did, paste all your given code.  return `400 bad request`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these helper methods which will make a cURL call to the graph API and return an application access_token.

This function takes a url and an array of parameters and makes a POST via cURL:

```
  function post_url($url, $params) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params, null, '&'));
    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ret;
  }
```

This function takes your app ID and secret provided in the [developer app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and returns an active access_token for your app:

```
  function get_app_access_token($app_id, $secret) {
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
    $token_params = array(
        "type" => "client_cred",
        "client_id" => $app_id,
        "client_secret" => $secret
        );
    return str_replace('access_token=', '', post_url($url, $token_params));
  }
```

You can call the method like so `$token = get_app_access_token('APP_ID','SEKRET');`

Comment: I have put my `app_id` and `app_secrect` in it, I tried `$token = get_app_access_token('APP_ID','SEKRET');` `echo $token`, get `400 bad request` I edit the code in my question

Comment: Can you post exactly how you're calling it without providing your entire secret? I just tried this with two separate applications and it works as expected.

Comment: which token is this? is this oAuth?

Comment: I get an empty string in the $token variable

Answer (score 2):

They really ought to make this clearer on the FB guide, but here's what worked for me. Unlike what a lot of people are saying online, you do NOT do a GET curl call but you still do a POST call.

So, the URL you post to will be "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"

And then, your POST variables that you'll feed CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will be something like:

```
"client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=" . urlencode("YOUR_URL") . "&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&code=YOUR_RECEIVED_CODE"
```

I was literally trying for at least 1.5 hours trying to get this to work.  Every time I went to the URL in a browser it was fine, and every time I tried to run a GET curl command, or a POST command where all the variables were still in the url (and not specified in POSTFIELDS) it failed.  It was really annoying.

Comment: thanks for more suggestion, acebook access_token will changed every 2 hours. It was really annoying. long days ago, I searched web, and see some guy said, he run the login script of his own account every hour, for saving the `access_token` to the database, then share the `access_token` to all his custom in his site. do search, post and any other thing. this is not an integrity method, but it real has some effect. I am pleasure talking with all around this topic. Thanks and merry x'mas